# I want to create a straight line connecting 2 JTable together

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jtable, jpanel

I want to create a straight line connecting 2 Jtables and when I move Jtable that line will still connect them.

Comment: Please clear define what you want to achieve and provide [mcve]. I cannot understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should override the method `paintChildren`. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 * <code>ConnectingPanel</code>.
 */
public class ConnectingPanel extends JPanel {

    private Component[] connectingComponents = new Component[2];

    private Color lineColor = Color.BLACK;

    @Override
    protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        if (connectingComponents[0] != null && connectingComponents[1] != null) {
            Color old = g.getColor();
            g.setColor(lineColor);
            Rectangle r1 = connectingComponents[0].getBounds();
            int x1 = r1.x + r1.width / 2;
            int y1 = r1.y + r1.height / 2;
            Rectangle r2 = connectingComponents[1].getBounds();
            int x2 = r2.x + r2.width / 2;
            int y2 = r2.y + r2.height / 2;
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            g.setColor(old);
        }

        super.paintChildren(g);
    }

    public void setConnectingComponent(Component c1, Component c2) {
        connectingComponents[0] = c1;
        connectingComponents[1] = c2;
    }

    public void setLineColor(Color lineColor) {
        this.lineColor = lineColor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Connecting test");
        JScrollPane scroller1 = new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(3, 5)));
        JScrollPane scroller2 = new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(3, 5)));
        ConnectingPanel cp = new ConnectingPanel();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(100, 100));
        cp.setConnectingComponent(scroller1, scroller2);
        cp.setLineColor(Color.RED);
        cp.add(scroller1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        cp.add(scroller2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JToggleButton vertButton = new JToggleButton("Arrange Vertical");
        vertButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            cp.removeAll();
            cp.add(scroller1, vertButton.isSelected() ? BorderLayout.NORTH : BorderLayout.WEST);
            cp.add(scroller2, vertButton.isSelected() ? BorderLayout.SOUTH : BorderLayout.EAST);
            cp.revalidate();
            cp.repaint();
            // provide enought space for frame
            frm.pack();
            frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        });
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(vertButton);
        frm.add(cp);
        frm.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i mean Drag and Drop Table with mouse to another position and Line will move with Table

Comment: The line will move with table when you implement D&D and call `revalidate`/`repaint` for ConnectingPanel. The problem is, that the correct implementing of D&D may take more time that I can spend for your problem.

Comment: when i tried to do that, the Line is draw on JTable, but i want to draw it under Jtable

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can understand what's wrong in your code.

Comment: I have link gitHub: https://github.com/HeoSolji/Ex, run it, and you can see what happen

Comment: No, sorry, when you want to get help, please provide a [mcve] here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time with me.It's hard to explain,this is part of a program analysis exercise, Graphics part, I want to make 2 Jtables  A and B (mxn pixels size) containing variable names, functions... and if A extends B, draw Line connecting A and B.

Comment: Have you looked in my example? Simply copy the class `ConnectingPanel` into your code and use it as holder for your tables.